# Convert Lua code to C++ classes back in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I've seen similar posts but none that quite asked the question in the same way.

Basically, I've been playing with Shiva3d lately ( http://www.stonetrip.com/ ), which is a 3d engine. The coding inside the engine is in Lua, however, the actual product when exported from the IDE is C++ code. While the coding is restricted, it does a fair job at exporting function, variables and everything back in C++ code.

What I want to know is, can I create a base engine, where there would be a set of predefined class and then use Lua to extend/overload these base classes (by providing certain predefined required functions) and get that code back in C++ with the different Lua/C++ binding libraries that exist?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't fully understand what it is you are describing. It sounds like you're saying that Shiva3D is somehow compiling Lua code into C++ code. That is, turning Lua into C++.

Comment: it is exactly what they are doing. Of course, the Lua code is only extending pre-defined C++ code and used to make programming faster and easier.

Comment: I want to see some evidence that Shiva is actually compiling Lua into C++. Because that seems both highly unlikely and exceedingly unnecessary. It's more likely that you're misinterpreting what they're doing.

Comment: Please refer to : http://s246.photobucket.com/albums/gg98/FrankBro/?start=all (order reversed for some reason). It shows what I mean perfectly.

Comment: What Shiva3D does, is using Lua as scriptinglanguage. The Lua scripts are **not** compiled into C++, in any way. They are called _from_ C++.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at SWIG http://www.swig.org/

It parses the C++ headers and creates binding for several languages (including Lua).

Comment: Can it export the Lua scripts extending these headers back to C++?

Answer (score 2):

Although I really like SWIG, I fell in love with [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html), because you have more direct control. Additionally it provides a built-in object orientation system and you do not need an additional translator/compiler like swig.

Comment: Can it export the Lua scripts extending these headers back to C++?

Comment: No, and I don't think that it would be useful. It enables the export of C++ functions/classes to lua, but not the other way around.